# Typoscript to render css bootstrap image column clearfix for every two columns?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, typo3, typoscript, typo3-6.2.x

So I have some elements with 6 image columns with captions on each image. Some captions are bigger than others, making the break of rows when on a mobile not well presented.

Bootstrap has this option to clearfix only the required viewport:

```
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2">.col-xs-6 .col-sm-2</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2">.col-xs-6 .col-sm-2</div>

    <!-- Add the extra clearfix for only the required viewport -->
    <div class="clearfix visible-xs-block"></div>

    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2">.col-xs-6 .col-sm-2</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2">.col-xs-6 .col-sm-2</div>

    <!-- Add the extra clearfix for only the required viewport -->
    <div class="clearfix visible-xs-block"></div>

    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2">.col-xs-6 .col-sm-2</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2">.col-xs-6 .col-sm-2</div>
</div>
```

If I can some how print the HTML like that using typoscript, it would be perfect.

The typoscript I have already adds the correct classes for the columns but I have no idea on how to print the  every two columns and not on the last one.

My typoscript:

```
addClassesCol.ifEmpty = 
addClassesCol.override.cObject = COA
addClassesCol.override.cObject {
    10 = CASE
    10 {
        key.field = imagecols

        default = TEXT
        default.value = col-md-12

        2 < .default
        2.value = col-sm-6 

        3 < .default
        3.value = col-sm-4 col-xs-6

        4 < .default
        4.value = col-sm-3 col-xs-6

        6 < .default
        6.value = col-sm-2 col-xs-6
    }
}
```

Any examples I can use to create that?

Comment: You could try `prepend` and `append`. More info here: http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Functions/Stdwrap/Index.html

Answer (score 0):

If you have 3 columns per row, apply clear:both to each third item.

Given HTML like this,

```
.row.apps
  .col-xs-6.col-sm-4.app-container
    .app
```

apply this CSS

```
.app-container:nth-child(2n+1) {
  clear: both;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: $screen-sm){
  .app-container:nth-child(3n+1) {
    clear: both;
  }
}
```

[Here you can find more details on my site and article.](https://gwhosaidthat.herokuapp.com/articles/6)